# How to load a web page containing CSS styles without affecting the loading web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change properties of a DIV in the html file which I've loaded in another HTML file. Example:

first HTML file is :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            div {
                 width:100%;
                 height:20vh;
                 background-color:red;
                 font-size:2rem;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>Hello</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

second HTML file:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('p').load('first.html');
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <p></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to change size and font-size of `div` from second HTML and don't want to change it from first HTML.

Comment: Remove the CSS from 'first.html', and use a single common stylesheet for all pages. Then override the styles in second.html by making the rules more specific in that page only. Also note that in your example the HTML would be invalid as you cannot have a block-level `div` element as a child of an inline `p` element

Comment: could you explain more about your saying that "making the rules more specific" @RoryMcCrossan ??